# How to mock a method in another class using PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking, phpunit

I have the following code below

```
class Main 
{
  function foo()
  {
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    $object = new CalculationObject($a, $b);
    return $object->calculate();
  }
}
```

```
class CalculationObject
{
  public $a;

  public $b;

  public function __construct($a, $b)
  {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
  }

  public function calculate()
  {
    return $this->a * $this->b;
  }
}
```

I am using PHPUnit to test it, however I am not able to find a possible way to mock the calculate method in Class Main.

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
class MainTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testFoo()
  {
    $main = $this->createPartialMock(Main::class, ['calculate']);

    $main->expects($this->once())
      ->method('calculate');
  }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: With such code you simply __can't__ mock anything. Because object of `CalculationObject` is created inside a tested method `foo`. You should somehow inject `CalculationObject` into Main class - either via constructor or as an argument to `foo` method.

Comment: How can I inject `CalculationObject` into Main class, knowing that it has arguments?

Comment: To be honest this is rather bad example for testing. In this case you should test that `CalculationObject->calculate` do what expected. And as nothing else happens in `Main` - there's no need to test it.

Comment: I put this just as an example of a scenario I currently have. function foo() does some other logic but all I care about is to mock the calculate method inside foo method

Comment: Fastest solution is to remove arguments in constructor in `CalculationObject`, add some setters instead. Then inject `CalculationObjectMock` with required mocked methods. More info on "dependency injection" search results.

Comment: I can't remove the arguments in CalculationObject as this will cause massive refactoring to that class. Would there be any other solution? Thanks

Comment: Is this project using a framework? Hope it does so it is easier to handle. For example, if you are using [tag:laravel] then it is way easier to test just because it has a [`Service Container`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#introduction) so it will handle `DI` among other things... Here, you have to take care of that yourself, you are reinventing the wheel...

Comment: This is using ZendFramework1

Comment: So, are you using [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework1)? It is abandoned since 2016, it is a must you migrate that to a new framework, but I totally understand if it is not 100% possible...

Comment: Yes totally aware that it is abandoned, have no other option to be honest, as it is a massive existing project. However the class that I wrote is pure PHP and all I care about is the structure to be able to test it or a way to mock.